# @Transactional annotation does not rollback RuntimeException even if @EnableTransactionManagement is provided

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, transactions, rollback

I have the following application setup:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

with a class which has the following:

```
public class DoStaff {

    public void doStaffOnAll(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
        for (int i=0; i<myObjects.size(); i++) {
            try {
                doStaffOnSingle(myObjects.get(i), i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStrackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doStaffOnSingle(MyObject myObject, int i) {
        repository.save(myObject);
        if (i%2==0) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
    
}
```

So if I call `DoStaff.doStaffOnAll` with a list of `MyObject`s, the code saves all element from the list but also throws a runtime exception for every second element.

Since the `doStaffOnSingle` has `@Transactional` annotation, I would expect that every second element will be rolled back.
But if I run this code, every element is saved in the DB successfully. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `@Transactional` doesn't apply when method call is internal to the class, only when `@Transactional` method is called from outside. Move the `doStaffOnAll()` to a different Spring component, and it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> In `proxy` mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with `@Transactional`. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your initialization code (that is, `@PostConstruct`).

Move the `doStaffOnAll()` to a different Spring component, and it'll work.

Or change to `aspectj` mode.

I would recommend moving the method, and design the code so transaction boundaries are clear and distinct, i.e. all public methods on the class starts a transaction, or no methods on the class starts a transaction.

It should always be very clear where your transaction boundaries are, e.g. in a layered design, you would normally make the `@Service` layer also be the transaction layer, i.e. any call from a higher layer to the service layer is an atomic transaction.

Answer (score 1):

`@Transactional` annotation is able to do the magic because of a proxy object.

Since you call the method directly you don't get that magic. In `doStaffOnAll` method you are directly invoking `doStaffOnSingle` method. So, nothing of Transactional behaviour gets added.

Try invoking the method using self invocation.

```
@Service
public class DoStaff {
    @Autowired
    private DoStaff doStaff;

    public void doStaffOnAll(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
        for (int i=0; i<myObjects.size(); i++) {
           doStaff.doStaffOnSingle(..) // invoke like this
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doStaffOnSingle(MyObject myObject, int i) {
       
    }
}
```

> Since the doStaffOnSingle has @Transactional annotation, I would
> expect that every second element will be rolled back.

The default Transactional mode will commit everything or nothing. I think you would want to use REQUIRES_NEW Propagation.

Look here for supported propagation types.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED