# How To: Allow @Transactional function to call another @Transactional function that fails and rolls back without rolling back first @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario where one @Transactional function is calling another and when the second one errors it rolls back transactions from both functions. Is there a way for me to prevent the first one from rolling back when the second one fails? Below is just an example, not the real scenario, but function A calls B and if B errors A tries to write an error to the DB. In this case when B fails, the save in A fails due to rollback.

Function A:

```
@Transactional
public void A(){
   try{
       String test = B();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //On error write the error to table
      ExecutionError error = new ExecutionError();
      error.setErrorId(GUIDUtil.uuid());
      error.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
      executionErrorDao.save(error);
   }
}
```

Function B:

```
@Transactional
public String B(){
   Person person = new Person();
   person.setPersonId(GUIDUtil.uuid());
   person.setPersonName("Person");
   personDao.save(person);
   return person.getPersonId();
}
```

Comment: I recently answered similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610779/11244881 . Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in B() did indeed solve the problem, thank you!